# How to use OAuth in Yii2 to authenticate with Jira?

Tags: php, oauth, yii2, jira-rest-api

Hope this is the right place.
I have a Project (web application) which should use OAuth to get access to our Jira-Server (through Jira REST API), but I don't know how to.

My web application's goal is, that it can fetch some data from Jira (sort by issue type, count up etc) and inject ist in a form (maybe input field). But before I can do that, I need a connection to our Jira-server via the Jira REST API. And OAuth should be used for authentication. I've already created an Application link in Jira.

I've tried these two libraries with a colleague, but none of them worked:

https://github.com/bmwcarit/silex-jira-oauth-provider (outdated)
https://github.com/mrjoops/oauth2-jira (doesn't support Jira-server)

tl;dr I need to know how to implement OAuth to authenticate to jira-server, to get access.